# GestureDetector.OnGestureListener on an activity that has a viewpager with multiple fragment tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to implement the down swipe and up swipe gesture in my activity in order to make visible an `editText` field inside one of the fragments of the viewPager in my activity. I can't implement it on the fragment itself since it has a gridView whose scrolling is getting affected and skewed.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event); // so that viewPager and other views also get the event
    // .. do your magic here (or at the start of this method)
}
```

Comment: how can I detect a swipe gesture in this method? sorry total noob. Also the editText is inside the fragment, how do I set it to be visible from the activity.